# Show Icon inside of TD Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
When I have the cursor inside of a td row, some icon should appear, and you should enable to click them. The icons contain link.

When you have the cursor in a new td row, the previous td row should be default and the new td row should have the new icon.

Pleae take a look at the picture.

Problem:
I don't know how to create it.

Information:
I'm using bootstrap, jquery and Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: You should probably show some code to before we can help you. You said you are using jQuery, why don't you use the hover event on the `<tr>` functionality?

Comment: Abijeet - Today, I don't have a code.

Comment: Roamer - in my definition, it is <tr><td><td></td></td><tr>

Comment: Actually, your problem doesn't require JS or jQuery at all. Good old CSS with :hover pseudo class will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can place all the icons when you are creating the rows. just give the style

```
style='display:none;'
```

then loop thorugh the rows via jquery

```
$(table tr).each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':hover')) 
      $('icondiv').show();
    else
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Then if you want to perform some action based on the click on those icons, then you can place an `data-*` attribute along with those icons and track that particular row.

From jquery you can fetch the `data` attributes using `data()` function like

```
$('icondiv').data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

**First way just use css** 
in html add class to div which include icons

```
<div class="IconsDiv">
    <!-- Icons here  -->
</div>
```

and in css

```
.IconsDiv{
    display: none;
}
tr:hover .IconsDiv{
    display: block;
}
```

**another way :** if you want to use jquery for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('table tr').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.IconsDiv').show();
   },function(){
      $(this).find('.IconsDiv').hide();
   });
});
```